# uplodify is not working with firefox

Tags: php, flash, firefox, yii, uploadify

I'm using `uploadify` in yii framework to upload files and it's working fine on Chrome and IE.

However, it throws an Http error on firefox!

Is there anyway to fix this or is it a bug or something ?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issuse by passing the session id

```
  'scriptData'=>array('SESSION_ID'=> session_id()),
```

and in the contraller

```
function init(){
            if(isset($_POST['SESSION_ID'])) {
                    $session=Yii::app()->getSession();
                    $session->close();
                    $session->sessionID = $_POST['SESSION_ID'];
                    $session->open();
            }
    }
```